# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' with Python WebCrawler

Tags: python, html, twitter, web-crawler

I'm writing a python program to crawl twitter using a combination of urllib2, the python twitter wrapper for the api, and BeautifulSoup. However, when I run my program, I get an error of the following type:

ray_krueger
RafaelNadal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Columbia Job\Python Crawler\Twitter Crawler\crawlerversion9.py", line 78, in <module>
    crawl(start_follower, output, depth)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Columbia Job\Python Crawler\Twitter Crawler\crawlerversion9.py", line 74, in crawl
    crawl(y, output, in_depth - 1)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Columbia Job\Python Crawler\Twitter Crawler\crawlerversion9.py", line 74, in crawl
    crawl(y, output, in_depth - 1)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Columbia Job\Python Crawler\Twitter Crawler\crawlerversion9.py", line 64, in crawl
    request = urllib2.Request(new_url)
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib2.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.__original = unwrap(url)
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib.py", line 1038, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I'm completely unfamiliar with this type of error (new to python) and searching for it online has yielded very little information. I've attached my code as well, but do you have any suggestions?

Thanx
Snehizzy

```
import twitter
import urllib
import urllib2
import htmllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

start_follower = "NYTimeskrugman" 
depth = 3
output = open(r'C:\Python27\outputtest.txt', 'a') #better to use SQL database thanthis

api = twitter.Api()

#want to also begin entire crawl with some sort of authentication service 

def site(follower):
    followersite = "http://mobile.twitter.com/" + follower
    return followersite

def getPage(follower): 
    thisfollowersite = site(follower)
    request = urllib2.Request(thisfollowersite)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return response

def getSoup(response): 
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return soup

def get_more_tweets(soup): 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id : 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        if str(b) == 'more':
            c = link['href']
            d = 'http://mobile.twitter.com' +c
            return d

def recordlinks(soup,output):
    tags = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : "list-tweet"})#to obtain tweet of a follower
    for tag in tags: 
        a = tag.renderContents()
        b = str (a)
        output.write(b)
        output.write('\n\n')

def checkforstamp(soup):
    times = nsoup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {'class': 'status_link'})
    for time in times:
        stamp = time.renderContents()
        if str(stamp) == '3 months ago':
            return True

def crawl(follower, output, in_depth):
    if in_depth > 0:
        output.write(follower)
        a = getPage(follower)
        new_soup = getSoup(a)
        recordlinks(new_soup, output)
        currenttime = False 
        while currenttime == False:
            new_url = get_more_tweets(new_soup)
            request = urllib2.Request(new_url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            new_soup = getSoup(response)
            recordlinks(new_soup, output)
            currenttime = checkforstamp(new_soup)
        users = api.GetFriends(follower)
        for u in users[0:5]:
            x = u.screen_name 
            y = str(x)
            print y
            crawl(y, output, in_depth - 1)
            output.write('\n\n')
        output.write('\n\n\n')

crawl(start_follower, output, depth)
print("Program done. Look at output file.")
```

Comment: The crawler essentially works by first identifying a follower and using beautiful soup to parse his/her page until I run into tweets that are 3 months old. Then it goes to the first five followers of each follower and so on - repeating the same process until it hits the depth that I specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
request = urllib2.Request(new_url)
```

in `crawl()`, `new_url` is `None`.  As you're getting `new_url` from `get_more_tweets(new_soup)`, that means `get_more_tweets()` is returning `None`.

That means `return d` is never being reached, which means either `str(b) == 'more'` was never true, or `soup.findAll()` didn't return any links so `for link in links` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that the way I wrote my code - I assumed each twitter user would have more than 1 page of tweets. However this does not appear to be the case for the 4th person I hit after crawling the tweets of the first three. Hence, when I get to that 4th user and my crawler attempts to find the link "more" which provides more tweets, it doesn't. It then returns None which causes the ultimate error. I'll try taking this into account in my code and keep you updated.

Comment: Scratch that. I just realized it was the second user - Rafael Nadal who was new to twitter and hence only had 1 page of tweets...Ha!

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

It means exactly what it says: `url.strip()` requires first figuring out what `url.strip` is, i.e. looking up the `strip` attribute of `url`. This failed because `url` is a `'NoneType' object`, i.e. an object whose type is `NoneType`, i.e. the special object `None`.

Presumably `url` was expected to be a `str`, i.e. a text string, since those do have a `strip` attribute.

This happened within `File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib.py"`, i.e., the `urllib` module. That's not your code, so we look backwards through the exception trace until we find something we wrote: `request = urllib2.Request(new_url)`. We can only presume that the `new_url` that we pass to the `urllib2` module eventually becomes a `url` variable somewhere within `urllib`.

So where did `new_url` come from? We look up the line of code in question (notice that there is a line number in the exception traceback), and we see that the immediately previous line is `new_url = get_more_tweets(new_soup)`, so we're using the result for `get_more_tweets`.

An analysis of this function shows that it searches through some links, tries to find one labelled 'more', and gives us the URL for the first such link that it finds. The case we haven't considered is when there are no such links. In this case, the function just reaches the end, and implicitly returns None (that's how Python handles functions that reach the end without an explicit return, since there is no specification of a return type in Python and since a value must always be returned), which is where that value is coming from.

Presumably, if there is no 'more' link, then we should not be attempting to follow the link at all. Therefore, we fix the error by explicitly checking for this `None` return value, and skipping the `urllib2.Request` in that case, since there is no link to follow.

By the way, this `None` value would be a more idiomatic "placeholder" value for the not-yet-determined `currenttime` than the `False` value that you are currently using. You might also consider being a little more consistent about separating words with underscores in your variable and method names to make things easier to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing: `request = urllib2.Request(new_url)`, `new_url` supposed to be a string, this error says it's `None`.

You get new_url's value from `get_more_tweets` function, so, it returned `None` somewhere.

```
def get_more_tweets(soup): 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id : 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        if str(b) == 'more':
            c = link['href']
            d = 'http://mobile.twitter.com' +c
            return d
```

When we look at this code, the function returns only when `str(b)=="more"` on some link, so your problem is "Why never str(b)=="more" happens?".

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `None` rather than a string to `urllib2.Request()`.  Looking at the code, this means that `new_url` is `None` sometimes. And looking at your `get_more_tweets()` function, which is the source of this variable, we see this:

```
def get_more_tweets(soup): 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id : 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        if str(b) == 'more':
            c = link['href']
            d = 'http://mobile.twitter.com' +c
            return d
```

This function is returning a value only if `b` is `"more"` because your `return` statement is indented under your `if`. If it is equal to any other value, no value (i.e. `None`) is returned.

You need to either always return a valid URL here, or you need to check for the `None` return value before passing it to `urllib2.Request()`.