# selenium/python downloading issues

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, download

I'm trying to use Selenium with python to automate a file download after trying/giving up with mechanize. I have done everything I think i should be doing with selenium, the forms fill out with what they should, buttons are clicked, etc. But my problem is nothing is downloading. Here are the relevant parts of my code (firefox profile included):

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir","Users/user/Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/tsv")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

...
...

```
elem=browser.find_element_by_class_name('data')
elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(9.0)
```

I use the sleep(9.0) because I'm just waiting around to see if the file needs more time to download. I can see the 'Submit' button being highlighted after the TABs but nothing seems to happen after that. Totally lost. I've googled a thousand times and can't seem to come up with anything.

Comment: You could use urllib for the download

Comment: I'm trying that right now from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919098/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-strip-with-python-webcrawle) suggestion but now I'm getting an Attribute error: object has no attribute 'strip

Comment: that sounds like its from something else

Comment: @Matt - long time to leave that question open. Maybe you can finally accept the only answer .

Answer (score 2):

Generally spoken, the download file chooser is part of the OS, not the browser, so you can't control it with selenium. I see two solutions:

1) Set the firefox profile settings in a way that no OS dependent dialog is shown. For that you need to change your profile into this:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
```

A link about this: http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/

2) The better solution is to not download the file at all with selenium. Have a read through this excellent article: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html
Basically this suggests to download the file outside of selenium.

Edit: I changed the link in the second option, since it was dead. Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: 1. I checked the link given in solution 2. I think it is for Java not python. 
2. before hitting here, I came across the solution given in point number 1. there again I failed to under stand what actually to do with "download". How to employ wget in code that too with url, id and cookies.

Comment: @sangharsh - indeed, the article is based on Java, but the message is independent of programming language I think.